# Error about created Let's Encrypt in AWS ubuntu server for flask web deployed

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nginx, lets-encrypt

I have applied a domain(for example example.com) from godaddy.com. And I run the command to create Let's Encrypt, but there is error.

```
(venv) ubuntu2@212.../microblog$ wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto
(venv) ubuntu2@212.../microblog$ chmod a+x ./certbot-auto
(venv) ubuntu2@212...~/microblog$ ../certbot-auto certonly --webroot -w /home/ubuntu2/microblog -d example.com --email example@aa.com
```

But there is error as following:

```
Requesting to rerun ./certbot-auto with root privileges...
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for example.com
Using the webroot path /home/ubuntu2/microblog for all unmatched domains.
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. example.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/V9B6Dz7gPx7RhyLmpYIlwYUhs1d4rWJF2HlpJbNbjbY: "<!DOCTYPE html><body style="padding:0; margin:0;"><html><body><iframe src="http://mcc.godaddy.com/park/MaO2MaO2LKWaYaOvrt==/fe/M"

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: example.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/V9B6Dz7gPx7RhyLmpYIlwYUhs1d4rWJF2HlpJbNbjbY:
   "<!DOCTYPE html><body style="padding:0;
   margin:0;"><html><body><iframe
   src="http://mcc.godaddy.com/park/MaO2MaO2LKWaYaOvrt==/fe/M"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

and the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/microblog as following

```
server {
# listen on port 80 (http)
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
location / {
# redirect any requests to the same URL but on https
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
}
server {
# listen on port 443 (https)
listen 443 ssl;
server_name example.com;
# location of the self-signed SSL certificate
#ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/microblog2/certs/cert.pem;
#ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/microblog2/certs/key.pem;
# write access and error logs to /var/log
access_log /var/log/microblog_access.log;
error_log /var/log/microblog_error.log;
location / {
# forward application requests to the gunicorn server
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
location /static {
# handle static files directly, without forwarding to the application
alias /home/ubuntu2/microblog/static;
expires 30d;
}
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
default_type "text/plain";
root /home/ubuntu2/microblog/;
}
location = /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
return 404;
}
}
```

[image: information about domain in godaddy]

I don't know where is wrong, could you help me solve this issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the error message that `example.com` is not pointing to your Nginx server address yet.  Notice this in the error message:

```
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/V9B6Dz7gPx7RhyLmpYIlwYUhs1d4rWJF2HlpJbNbjbY:
   "<!DOCTYPE html><body style="padding:0;
   margin:0;"><html><body><iframe
   src="http://mcc.godaddy.com/park/MaO2MaO2LKWaYaOvrt==/fe/M"  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

The `godaddy.com/park` part likely means that the domain is parked at GoDaddy, and is *not* reaching your server yet.

The error message provide is also useful to understand the problem:

```
  To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

Check DNS settings, and try again. Also note - it could be DNS propagation time related, it the DNS change was recent. In that case you need to wait for the change to be propagated, up to 24 hours.

Ps You can confirm that by running `curl example.com` on the command line.  Make sure it returns the home page of your server.  When it does, try again.

Comment: hi thanks for your comments, when I curl example.com, the result is following:   <html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>

Comment: hi I have updated the domain information in godaddy site. I can't follow the sentence:DNS propagation time related

Comment: Get rid of 301 redirect to https. You can not redirect to https until after you have properly configured SSL.